# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0, the number of rows contained in an existing section after update

Tags: swift, uitableview, delete-row

I keep getting this error when I swipe and delete a `UITableCell`

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath)
    tableView.reloadData()
    print(listOfCoins)
    print(listOfCoins.count)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}

func deleteAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, nil) in
        self.listOfCoins.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    action.title = "Delete"
    action.backgroundColor = .red
    return action
}
```

I've tried taking out "self.tableView.deleteRows" which allows the app to run and deletes the indexPath from my source, but I don't know why the cell doesn't disappear when 'tableView.reloadData()' is called afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only need

```
self.listOfCoins.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

So remove this

```
let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath)
tableView.reloadData() // remove this line
```

And

```
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.reloadData() // remove this line
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath) 
    print(listOfCoins)
    print(listOfCoins.count)
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}

func deleteAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, nil) in
        self.listOfCoins.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) 
    }
    action.title = "Delete"
    action.backgroundColor = .red
    return action
}
```

Comment: If I delete "let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath)" what am I supposed to return? It's supposed to return a UISwipeActionConfiguration.